# Getting a relationshipID from a shape

Tags: c#, openxml

How do I get the relationshipID from a shape that I know the name of? I am working with C# and OpenXML. I need a method that accepts the slide and the name of the shape I am looking for and that returns the relationshipID as a string:

```
public static String GetShapeRId (Slide slide, String name)
{
    var shapes = slide.ChildElements;

    foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
    {
        if (shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Name == name)
        {
            return shape.RelationshipID; // This is the part I am looking for
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Can somebody help me out. Also: should my loop work? I am kind of new at C# and OpenXML and always open for suggestions and improvements.